# Difficulty in Removing Items From List?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists. The first is of all students and the second is of selected students. I want if I one time select some student they will remove from the all-student list. Here is my code but it doesn't. Students won't get removed.

```
foreach (var li in ListSelectedStudents.ToList())
{
    if (ListAllStudents.Contains(li))
    {
        ListAllStudents.Remove(li);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: no i dont get any error but students not remove from my allstudentlist

Comment: @MichałCiuruś: That's not the issue here - the OP isn't iterating over the list they're removing from.

Comment: Is `ListAllStudents.Contains(li)` ever true, are the same (or equal) instances being used in both `ListSelectedStudents` and `ListAllStudents`? Please show all relevant code used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: _"I have two lists"_ The most important question: what kind of lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried using linq:

```
ListAllStudents.RemoveAll(m => ListSelectedStudents.Contains(m));
```

if it does not work, it could be something wrong with the default comparison implemented in the object, and you could either fix the comparer, or do something like:

```
ListAllStudents.RemoveAll(m => ListSelectedStudents.Any(n=>n.Id == m.Id)); // Assume the Id is the primary key of the object...
```

Comment: +1 I couldn't get my head into gear for a non-`IEquatable` alternative, although the relative performance will be different in the linq implementation, the implementation itself is nice and succinct.

Comment: fixing the behind object to implement IEquatable would be nicer in fact - it would eliminate the need to use linq and predicate at the places where comparison is required... i guess the original code did not use customized objects, or the objects are not properly used - in theory simple object should not be re-produced multiple times and stored at different collections.

Answer (score 4):

`Contains` will use equality to determine what is "equal", I am assuming here that your custom class hasn't provided a custom equality implementation, which means the default equatable will be provided for that type and it's just using reference equality. So even though you think two things are "equal", the `Contains` method doesn't and so doesn't step into the `Remove` call.

To get that particular code to behave what you need to do is provide an implementation of `IEquatable<Student>` on the `Student` class, as described in the remarks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In this instance, `Contains` isn't actually required as `Remove` will do the same checks. If there is nothing to remove, the `Remove` call will be transparent, effectively doing nothing.

As has been caught in the comments before I had chance to provide the information, `Remove` will also rely on `IEquatable<Student>` ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) so you still need to provide an implementation, but it will make your code look a little cleaner:

```
foreach (var li in ListSelectedStudents.ToList())
{
    ListAllStudents.Remove(li);
}
```

There may be various ways to do this without the need to implement the interface, but you won't be able to use your current code for it. I'll leave other answers to field those alternatives as it's Friday and my brain is not yet functioning properly.

Comment: I assume that it's `ListItem` where `Equals` is overridden. But both must be of type `ListItem` and both must have the same `Text` **and** `Value`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have no idea, there is a lot of backing information missing from the question. I just read "a list of students" so assumed a custom class was hanging around somewhere. If it's not a custom class that they can control, my answer may no longer be entirely correct.

Comment: Yes, i'm also just guessing because of the common abbreviation. Imho nobody should answer such questions until OP hasn't clarified it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I had that opinion once, but needless to say I'm quite disenfranchised about the altruistic aspects of SO (half-baked questions being one of them, people providing duplicate answers being another, the list goes on) so I'll provide a potentially useful answer and remove/amend it if the facts change. Half the problem is people don't tidy up or maintain their old answers. We'll gloss over the part where you had originally provided an answer ;-)

Comment: I've provided an answer at a time i thought that the issue was clear even if i was missing details(like involved types).  Apart from that my argument was not aimed against you but this kind of questions.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I know, I agree with you. I'm just saying my approach is to provide an answer in the face of current facts if one is attainable and also attempt to address your concerns by keeping an eye on my answer with regards to the question changing over time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ListSelectedStudents = ListSelectedStudents.Where(a => !ListSelectedStudents.Contains(a)).Select(a => a).ToList();
```