# Diffculty In removing Item From List

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two lists. The first is of all Team member **list1** and the
second is of selected team member **list2**. i want to remove selected
team member **list2** items from **list1** Here is my code but it
doesn't. Students won't get removed.

```
foreach (var list in list2.ToList())
{
   if (list1.Contains(list))
   {
       list1.Remove(list);
   }
}
```

Comment: check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562765/difficulty-in-removing-items-from-list?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following will remove items from list1:

```
list1.RemoveAll(l => list2.Contains(l));
```

Alternative solution - you can create new list with items from list1 except items from list2 (note - it will remove duplicates also):

```
var result = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

And if you need only enumerate result, then you even don't need to create list - you can remove `ToList()` call.

---

NOTE: if you are dealing with custom objects instead of primitive types (int, string, etc) then by default your objects will be compared by references. I.e. if all fields of objects are equal, but thats a different instances of your class, then they will be considered not equal. In order to compare objects by values of their fields you should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of your class, or create custom comparer for your class.

Comment: well you're right sorry

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work if the list contains strings. I suspect your two lists contain different objects for each student - so the object for Jim in list1 is not the same object for Jim as in list2.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me I think this can solve your problem

```
    List<String> planguages=new ArrayList<String>();
    planguages.add("Ajax");
    planguages.add("Java");
    planguages.add("Python");

    List<String> planguages2=new ArrayList<String>();
    planguages2.add("Ajax");
    planguages2.add("Java");
    planguages2.add("Python");
    planguages2.add("C#");
    planguages2.add("c++");

    if(planguages2.containsAll(planguages)){
        planguages2.removeAll(planguages);
        System.out.println(planguages2.size());
        System.out.println("ok");
    }else{
        System.out.println("nok");
    }
```